# How to get changes from another branch that don't affect your pull request?

Tags: git, pull-request

I want to get changes from a branch into my branch but I don't want that these changes appear in my pull request, how can I do it?

I did a merge into my branch but my pr has all the commits.

Comment: A PR will include all changes on your branch that aren't in the target branch. If you don't want certain changes to be part of a PR, then don't put those changes into the branch getting PR'd. Whatever the reason is that you want some changes from another branch to be in your branch, maybe you can just make a separate branch for that?

Comment: Please specify what website (I assume github.com or gitlab.com?) or on-site git server software this is about. As pull requests work slightly differently on each platform, the answer may vary.